# Area target of Vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I updated my Vuforia Engine in Unity, but when I add a area target it keep me saying this:

```
MissingMethodException: bool UnityEngine.Texture2D.Reinitialize(int,int,UnityEngine.TextureFormat,bool)
Vuforia.Image.CopyBufferToTexture (UnityEngine.Texture2D texture) (at <c743aea6c8934ed0bde7bea935120b03>:0)
Vuforia.Internal.Utility.GLTFLoading.GLTFTexture.GetTexture () (at <c743aea6c8934ed0bde7bea935120b03>:0)
Vuforia.Internal.Utility.GLTFLoading.GLTFTexture.get_Texture () (at <c743aea6c8934ed0bde7bea935120b03>:0)
Vuforia.Internal.Utility.GLTFLoading.GLTFExtractorUtility.AddGameObject (Vuforia.Internal.Utility.GLTFLoading.GLTFNode node, UnityEngine.Transform parentTransform, System.Boolean isRoot) (at <c743aea6c8934ed0bde7bea935120b03>:0)
Vuforia.Internal.Utility.GLTFLoading.GLTFExtractorUtility.CreateMeshes () (at <c743aea6c8934ed0bde7bea935120b03>:0)
Vuforia.EditorClasses.GLTFAssetCreator.LoadGLTFMeshes () (at <811afcd41f124d7a8beb7ca1ca5de3bb>:0)
Vuforia.EditorClasses.ExtractorUtilities.ExportAndSaveMeshAndTextureData (System.String rootFolder, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] glTFFiles, System.String prefabFileName) (at <811afcd41f124d7a8beb7ca1ca5de3bb>:0)
UnityEngine.Debug:LogException(Exception)
Vuforia.EditorClasses.ExtractorUtilities:ExportAndSaveMeshAndTextureData(String, List`1, String)
Vuforia.EditorClasses.ExtractorUtilities:ExtractAndSaveAuthoringGLB(String, String)
Vuforia.EditorClasses.GLBTypedAreaTargetExtractor:ExtractModel(String, String)
Vuforia.EditorClasses.CADModelExtractor:CreateAreaTargetPrefabs(String, IEnumerable`1)
Vuforia.EditorClasses.CADModelExtractor:CreateAreaTargetPrefabs()
Vuforia.EditorClasses.CADModelExtractor:CreateAreaTargetPreviewPrefab()
Vuforia.EditorClasses.ModelExtractionOfAreaTargetsTask:Execute()
Vuforia.EditorClasses.<>c:<OnPostprocessAllAssets>b__1_0(VuforiaLifeCycleTask)
System.Collections.Generic.List`1:ForEach(Action`1)
Vuforia.EditorClasses.AssetPostProcessTaskRunner:OnPostprocessAllAssets(String[], String[], String[], String[])
UnityEditor.AssetPostprocessingInternal:PostprocessAllAssets(String[], String[], String[], String[], String[])
```

Anyone had this problem?

I used to use area target and I never had this problem.

Thanks

Use Area Target of Vuforia.